# NSubstitute actually calling the function when doing a .received().functionName() check?

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I am not sure whether this is because of a problem in my NSubstitute code or my product code, but sometimes my test is failing with the exception being thrown which I actually intend to catch. I will write down a small piece to code below to represent what I am doing.

```
// test code for function A in class A
public void Test_FunctionA_CatchesException(){
    IClassB classb = Substitute.For<IClassB>();
    classb.FunctionB().Returns(x => { return 5; }, x => { Console.WriteLine("inside mock function"); throw new Exception("exception message"); });
    ClassA classa = new ClassA(classb);
    classa.FunctionA();
    Console.WriteLine("Function A call complete");
    classb.Received(2).FunctionB();
    Console.WriteLine("function B received check complete");
}

// product code Class A

public class ClassA {
    public void FunctionA() {
        try {
            int x = classb.FunctionB();
            classb.FunctionB();
        } catch (Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Is there something wrong in the way that I am throwing the exception? Function B is a normal function that returns int. This unit test although mostly works fine, threw exception one time (the exception that I am throwing in FunctionB call). Sadly I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior as well.

UPDATE:

I was able to reproduce the error. I used NCrunch to run this test until failure. With some console logging I was able to narrow down the problem. (I have updated the code above as well). In the substituted FunctionB() call I have added Console.WriteLine to know when this function is being called (since its not possible to debug it using breakpoints as it rarely fails).

What I have observed is that when the test succeeds, it prints the below:

inside mock function

Function A call complete

function B received check complete

But when it fails it prints the below:

inside mock function

Function A call complete

inside mock function

and then the exception stack trace. So somehow when I am doing Received(2).FunctionB(), instead of checking the receives its actually doing a function call.

Comment: "Sadly I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior as well" which makes the issue pretty hard. Maybe you did not re-compile your SuT? Or your actual code does not fit the provided code above.

Comment: @HimBromBeere. What do you mean by SuT? I have actually checked multiple times that the issue fits the above case.

Comment: @HimBromBeere , Actually the return statement for the substitute in my code was a bit different (updated the code above). Could this return type of returning be an issue. My other unit tests have return like this: .Returns(x => throw new Exception()) but this one has: .Returns(x => {throw new Exception();})

Comment: SuT = System under test. I ment: did you recompile your assembly and your test-code? Maybe it´s a timestamp-issue.

Comment: Its an automated system that automatically recompiles and runs the unit tests multiple times when some condition is met. The unit test threw error in one of those runs.

Comment: Try adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to the test project. It can pick up some problems that might be causing this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidTchepak , NSubstitute.Analyzers didnt find any issues.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have updated the question with more details if you know something.